# Can't include jpg image

Tags: graphics

I am new to LaTeX and trying to learn it by writing a CV. I tried to add a photo of me in the document. The code is below:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
  \begin{figure}[h!]
    \centering
      \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{taufique}
  \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

'taufique' is the name of the jpg image file. It's located in the same directory where tex file is placed. I compiled with pdflatex but it is not being compiled. Error report says that compiler can't find the image file. What's the problem?

Comment: Try to use `\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{taufique.jpg}`. If you are on a Unix-like system there might also be some confusion, if the file has the extension `.JPG` or `.jpeg`, in whatever combination ...

Comment: You need to compile with pdflatex, not latex. Have you done this?

Comment: Christian, Did that. Not working.
Werner, Yes I did. I mentioned it in the question too.

Comment: @taufique: 'Silly question' by me: Do you have read access to that graphics file?

Comment: @ChristianH, saw the properties. Both read and write is permitted.

Comment: @taufique: Did you try the tests with your MWE you posted above or are you using another file? Did you test, whether you can include some graphics file, 'just for fun'?

Comment: @ChristianH. didn't get you, sorry.

Comment: @taufique: Did you try to include some other graphics file, just in order to see, whether that works?

Comment: No I didn't. I am very new to it. I just copied and pasted the code from latex wikibook. Can you shade me more light.

Comment: As it stands, this looks like the usual 'what file formats' issue: we'll need a log file to get any further.